# How function 'receive' in Java socket designed?

Tags: java, sockets

As we know, we use similar code with following one to receive a packet using UDP socket:

```
DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
s.receive(p);
```

I'd like to know why function `receive()` rather setting a passed packet than returning a packet object.

Why this API designed like this? What advantages such design method has, and what for disadvantages?

Comment: Because that's the way they designed it. `DatagramChannel.receive()` is designed the way you suggest. No other answer possible unless you get the designer on the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look at your code, you find that the "user" defines that **buffer** array which will later be used by the socket to actually store data.

Therefore the user of this API is in **full** control about the memory/buffers that will get used.

Of course, this makes it also "more complicated" to use that interface. But when you are dealing with such **low level** interfaces, chances are that you *want* to be able to control such subtle details.

Meaning: when you are down into the realms of "I do my own datagram protocol implementation", then you really know why you are doing that. And then "more degrees" of freedom are a good thing.

Or alternatively, the explanation by JB Nizet is reasonable, too: this API is basically 17+ years old. Chances are that is a simple "copy" of what people were doing with C/C++ at that point in time.

Coming from there: if one would be to create a "fresh" API for this purpose, it would most likely look much different and more "abstract" nowadays.

Comment: Since the class is so old (JDK 1.0), I also wonder, though, if its designed was not simply copied on a C-based design, and/or if the designers didn't chose this design because they were afrad (for good reasons at that time), that creating many short-lived byte arrays and DatagramPacket objects wouldn't be efficient enough. The chose design allows reusing the same byte array and the same packet for many/all receivals.

Comment: That's reasonable. By the way, this low-level API actually makes me get a further understand on socket, rather than a more abstract one (e.g. socket in Python).

Comment: @syxbyi Feel free to express your appreciation for my input by providing an upvote, now that you reached that level. And remember about accepting one of the answers ... at some point ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to know why function receive() rather setting a passed packet
>   than returning a packet object.

Passing a parameter in `receive()` matters as `DatagramSocket` allows to 
set a buffer for holding the incoming datagram but overall **to specify the number of bytes to read**.
It is done via the `DatagramPacket` parameter :

> The length field of the datagram packet object contains the length of
>   the received message. **If the message is longer than the packet's
>   length, the message is truncated**.

As you noticed, `DatagramPacket` is also needed after the  `receive()` return as among other things, the `DatagramPacket`'s buffer is filled with data send by the client.

The method could be defined with a distinct parameter in input specific to the receive configuration and another in output specific to the information send by the client. For example :

```
public synchronized DatagramPacketOutput receive(DatagramPacketInput p) throws IOException {
```

but API designers chose to use a single parameter and to use it as an input-output parameter.
Note that the synchronization on the `receive()` methods relies on a lock of the `DatagramPacketInput` parameter :

```
public synchronized void receive(DatagramPacket p) throws IOException {
    synchronized (p) {
         ...
    }
   ...
}
```

I assume that returning `void` is a way to emphasis it.